# Creating threads to process multiple objects C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, loops, for-loop

first of all let me say you're a great community. I've visited this website hundreds of times and I always got help!

But still, I am quite new at programming and there is something I can't find the answer in the internet, so I am going to ask it here to see if I can get some help. Also, my English is not very good so I apology in advance, I hope you guys understand my question:

I need to do a multithread program in C++ to create maximum 5 threads that process a std::vector with 100 objects within it. So here is my question: How should I create the loops? In order to create 5 threads, an each one process a single object. So when a thread finishes it can continue with the next one.

```
void * threaded_objectProcessor (void *voidArg)
{
//process the object
}


main()
{
//beginning of my code


    for (std::vector<myObject>::iterator it = myVector.begin(); it != myVector.end(); it++)
    {
        //don't know what to do here
    }    
//rest of my code
 }
```

I hope I explained myself enough, and thank you guys in advance, any help is welcome.

Antirreni91

Comment: If you are on C++11 and there are fixed 100 objects in the vector, you could create 5 times a `std::thread` and let each thread work on 100/5 items.

Comment: Have you read some C++ threading tutorials? They would be a good starting point, and should explain what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: General advice. Parallel programming is hard. In 2015, before proceed with raw primitives like threads, locks, atomics etc., I would rather recommend to start with some mature library or framework to see how they do it. As an example, [Intel Threading Building Blocks](https://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/) is a relatively simple to use, extensible, hardware-friendly and, thus, fast Task Parallelism library. It is open source, so you can always find out 'how it works'. You can revert to handwritten stuff later, if you feel strong enough (but most times you will not want to).

Comment: In my opinion the simplies framework is openmp, `tbb` is harder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple solution is to use `openmp` library. It needs `-fopenmp` compiler flag and your application must be linked to `libgomp` library.
Also your code need modifications:

```
for (std::vector<myObject>::iterator it = myVector.begin(); it != myVector.end(); it++)
{
    //don't know what to do here
}
```

Must be changed to definitive-end-condition for the compiler. After all the changes your code will look like this:

```
const size_t count = myVector.size();
#pragma omp parallel for num_threads(5)
for (size_t i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
    // or change this how you want to work with your vector
    threaded_objectProcessor(myVector[i]);
}
```

Comment: To OP: And remember that, depending on the processing, multithreaded version may actually take longer to run than a single-threaded one. So if you see it - don't be surprised :-).